# RestKit Login problem

Tags: ios, restkit

Can anyone give me a hint why I can not login into my service? I dont get an response to my delegate. The service is working. If I call the url in my browser I get a login (Browser receives a cookie) and then I can call request on my service:

Here is my Code:

```
RKClient *client =[RKClient clientWithBaseURL:@"https://myserverinstance/mobileapp/"];

NSString *loginString = @"SSO.login?application=myAppName&language=en&username=MyUserName&password=MyPassword&permanentLogin=true";

    [RKClient setSharedClient:client];
    if([[RKClient sharedClient] isNetworkAvailable]){;
        NSLog(@"Network is available");
        [[RKClient sharedClient] get:loginString delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the typos in your posted code (e.g. `if([[RKClient sharedClient] isNetworkAvailable]){;`) do not exist in your actual project.

Are your SSL certificates self-signed? If so, you'll need to set the `RESTKIT_SSL_VALIDATION` preprocessor directive. You'll also need to link against `Security.framework`.

If your certificates *are* signed by a common authority, then you should post more information about your problem. Turn RestKit logging on with `RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);` and see if that provides any hints to where the problem really lies.